# OAuth2 with JWT tokens generation error using Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oauth, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm a beginner in FastApi and I'm trying the FastApi [tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) for SQL with OAuth authentication. So far I've managed to create crud for users with password hashing. However now I'm trying the JWT token generation function when user trying to log in but I'm getting confused how to replace actual PostgresSQL database instead the given fake_database example in tutorial. I tried replacing fake_database with `db: Session` but now I get this error.

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped

main.py file

```
@app.post("/token", response_model=schemas.Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    user = crud.authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = crud.create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

crud.py file

```
def authenticate_user(db: Session, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user_for_authentication(db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.password):
        return False
    return user


def get_user_for_authentication(db: Session, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return schemas.UserInDB(**user_dict)
```

schemas.py file

```
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserBase(BaseModel):
    username: str
    name: Optional[str] = None
    email: Optional[str] = None

class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: List[Item] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class UserInDB(UserBase):
    password: str

class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str

class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str
    
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Optional[str] = None
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're now sending in an actual db session, you need to query the db as you would with regular sqlalchemy methods.

The error message is caused by:

```
if username in db:
```

Which attempts to check if the `str` is in the current db session - that won't work, since it's meant to check if a given returned SQLAlchemy object is already present in the current db session.

You would replace it with something like:

```
db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.username == username).first()
```

Depending on how your user model in SQLAlchemy is structured.

Comment: get_user = get_user_by_username(db,username)
    if get_user.username == username:
        # user_dict = get_user[username]
        return schemas.UserInDB(**get_user)

I edited the function like this but now I get this error : ModelMetaclass object argument after ** must be a mapping, not User

Comment: Yes, use `schemas.UserInDB.from_orm(get_user())`  in that case; but you can freely pass the retrieved User object around instead of converting it to a schema object.